# How to select some particular text right after <li> with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have something like that :

```
<ul>
  <li>
    ...
  </li>
  <li>
    Office
    <table>
      .......
    </table>
  </li>
</ul>
```

And i want to replace `Office` with `<h3>Office</h3>` so i did :

```
$("li:contains('Office')").replaceWith('<h3>Office</h3>');
```

But it's replacing me all the `<li>` (so it deletes the table too...) I know it's normal but how to replace just the text `Office` please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `.contents` and `.eq` to select just the first node.

```
 $("li:contains('Office')").contents().eq(0).replaceWith('<h3>Office</h3>');
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/ppqvt/

Answer (score 1):

You can use [contents()](http://api.jquery.com/contents/) to obtain all the direct children of your `<li>` element, and [filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) to accumulate the text nodes that occur before the `<table>` element.

From there, you can use [wrapAll()](http://api.jquery.com/wrapAll/) to create an `<h3>` element around the text nodes:

```
var $contents = $("li:contains('Office')").contents();
var tableIndex = contents.index("table");
$contents.filter(function(index) {
    return this.nodeType == 3 && index < tableIndex;
}).wrapAll("<h3>");
```